# Rails 6 fontawesome production purge

Tags: webpack, font-awesome, ruby-on-rails-6

To include fontawesome-pro in my project I have a line in my packs/application.js
`import "fontawesome-pro/js/all"`.

This creates a massive bloat and the compiled asset file is over 6Mb!  What is the accepted method of only including actually used icons in the Rails 6 production webpack file when using font-awesome?

I can see some instructions at https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/turbolinks but these don't really explain very much (and refuse to work).

(ps: using rails-turbo not turbolinks)